# How to use NetworkWorker methods from a pallet?

Tags: substrate-node-template, networking

I'm using NodeTemplate to build my blockchain and it seems that NetworkWorker is too low level kind of thing. Particularly I need a way to manage connected peers (list, disconnect).

Comment: What is `NetworkWoker`? Could add some links/details?

Comment: https://crates.parity.io/sc_network/struct.NetworkWorker.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.